# Coroutine was never awaited in Tornado

Tags: asynchronous, tornado, coroutine

I'm trying to learn asynchronous call in Python, and here's my code:

```
class MyClient:
   def _init_(self):
    
   async def method(self):
      print("xxxxxxx")
```

And also:

```
def test_my_client():
    @coroutine
    def test_async_client():
        client = MyClient()
        return client.method()
    result = IOLoop.run_sync(test_async_client)
    print(result)
```

So basically I used `IOLoop.run_sync` to async call `client.method()`, but I can never see traces from `print('xxxxxx')` as if `client.method()` has never been triggered. Also there's a warning that `coroutine client.method was never awaited`

If I `print(result)`, I'll see `<coroutine object client.method at >`, so coroutine object is returned, and I understand the awaitable object is returned and will be resolved or executed? Has the `client.method()` been executed? And if so how can I check the content of the object and see the print traces?

Answer (score 0):

`IOLoop.run_sync` expects a callable (function, coroutine), not an awaitable (Future) object.

That means, don't call the function, just pass the function itself:

```
result = IOLoop.run_sync(test_async_client)
```

**UPDATE:**

Also, you've to await the `client.method()` coroutine. As you're still using the old `@coroutine` decorator (but why?), you can't use the `await` keyword. However, you can try using the `yield` keyword to await the Future:

```
result = yield client.method()
return result
```

BTW, you should just use the new `async def` syntax instead of the old `@coroutine` decorator to make things easier.

Comment: Thanks I fixed it but still no luck. Coroutine still never awaited. I know in Asyncio we have ```run_until_complete()``` to fix this issue, but what's the equivalent of this in Tornado?

Comment: @LookIntoEast You'll have to await the `MyClient.method` coroutine when you call it. I've updated the answer.